# preg_replace with multiple values

Tags: php, regex

I have an array with multiple values called `$my_replacements`.

I have a string called `$my_string`.

I want to be able to iterate over $my_replacements and perform a preg_replace on $my_string, so right now I have this:

```
foreach($my_replacements as $replacement) {
    preg_replace($replacement, '', $my_string);
}
```

This works fine, but I would just like the loop to stop when a replacement is done to $my_string, and when that happens I want to get the value of this new $my_string with the value replaced out of it.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare the result with the string before replacing something:

```
foreach($my_replacements as $replacement) {
     $new_string = preg_replace($replacement, '', $my_string);
     if($new_string !== $my_string) {
         break;
     }
}
```

[From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> If matches are found, the new subject will be returned, **otherwise subject will be returned unchanged** or NULL if an error occurred.

If this is not the case, we break, i.e. exit the loop.